# RecyclerView items with very large empty space at bottom after updating to support library 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have updated support library to 23.2.1 and after that recyclerview items are appearing with big empty space.
Though I am using recyclerview and it's parent view height as WRAP_CONTENT.
My App fetches 10 items data at a time from the server and while scrolling to up it shows a progressbar at the bottom so at that time(while progressbar is showing) recyclerview items are showing with very large empty space.

[image]

Code for xml files for fragment and adapter repectively :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

    <include layout="@layout/date_picker_layout"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sort_view_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sort_view_height"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/sort_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/date_picker_selector"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
            android:id="@+id/low_to_high"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_down"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
            android:id="@+id/high_to_low"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_up"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/three_dot"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
        android:text="@string/coming_soon"
        android:id="@+id/no_items"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemview">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_image_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <com.example.views.CircularProgressWheel
        android:layout_width="@dimen/progressbar_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/progressbar_height"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="@color/primary"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:text="@string/location"
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:id="@+id/price_actual"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/price_actual"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/price_actual" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/cancel_button_selector"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/sold_out"
        android:id="@+id/sold_out"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your recycler view height is set to `wrap_content`. [23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) introduced wrap content functionality for RecylerView and you should have the height as wrap_content if you want your RecyclerView work as it was working before.

Quote from [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of
>   your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as
>   MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

Comment: getting the same behaviour either I set it to match_parent or wrap_content

Comment: Can you please post some code ? Your adapter item xml and recyclerview xml would be ideal.

Comment: I have posted the code for both layouts

Comment: Not sure if you already solved this or not.
I'm using support library version 23.4.0 and followed the suggestions above, but still facing the same problem as yours.
Using wrap_content for item views, will display the items properly, but after you scroll it, there will be large gap between item. In my case i tried to set the RecylerView(not the item view) back to match_parent.
To put it, in my case:
- RecyclerView is match_parent
- Item view is wrap_content
May be it will work to in your case.

Comment: My progressbar's layout width was MATCH_PARENT that's why is was appearing on the full screen, after setting it to WRAP_CONTENT my problem is solved.

Comment: in my case, the xml linked to my Adapter class on method onCreateViewHolder had a RelativeLayout with android:layout_heigh="match_parent", I changed it to "wrap_content" andit worked fine!