# Android RecyclerView large gap space after some rows of items on tablet landscape

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, tablet, spacing

There are large random placed gaps appearing in between the rows of views in my RecyclerView, same like other users noted in bellow questions.

I have looked into suggested solutions from other questions like:

[Large gap forms between RecyclerView items when scrolling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817610/large-gap-forms-between-recyclerview-items-when-scrolling-down)

[Large gap between RecyclerView items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476611/large-gap-between-recyclerview-items)

[RecyclerView items with big empty space after 23.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728179/recyclerview-items-with-big-empty-space-after-23-2-0)

[Android RecyclerView Blank Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522509/android-recyclerview-blank-space)

[RECYCLERVIEW SPACE BETWEEN ITEMS ON ANDROID APPLICATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521577/recyclerview-space-between-items-on-android-application)

[RecyclerView items with very large empty space at bottom after updating to support library 23.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068857/recyclerview-items-with-very-large-empty-space-at-bottom-after-updating-to-suppo)

but they all seam to suggest the same thing: change match_parent to wrap_content in your layouts. As it can be seen from the layout code bellow, I have tried that, but I still get the same gaps.

I need to note that these gaps are present only in tablets in the landscape.

My layouts:

content_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

content_main.xml in layout-sw600pd-port:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/llTwoPane"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:baselineAligned="true"
              android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/gap_xl"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        android:name=".MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/parts_fd"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml in layout-sw600pd

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/llTwoPane"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:baselineAligned="true"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/gap_xl">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        android:name=".MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/parts_fm"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/parts_fd"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llFragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnSort"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/title_gap"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/title_gap"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_m"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/gap_m"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPosters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/half_poster_spacing"
        android:background="@color/colorLight"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml inflated in adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flPosterItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_poster_spacing"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvPoster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/poster_content_description"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFavouriteInMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/fav_button_minw"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fav_button_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fav_button_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/fav_button_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fav_button_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/fav_button_padding"
        android:background="@color/colorButtonStarBgd"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_m"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

I set my RecyclerView with:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(posterAdapter.getGridLayoutManager());
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(posterAdapter);
```

And grid layout manager is set with:

```
GridLayoutManager getGridLayoutManager() {
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, mNumberOfColumns);
    gridLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
    gridLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(mNumberOfColumns);
    return gridLayoutManager;
}
```

On phones gaps don't appear in any orientation. On tablets, in portrait there is only one column. Even with match_parent the gaps do not appear. In landscape there are three to four columns and gaps appear even with wrap_content and it's always between full rows.

I have tried to remove

- `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`
- `ridLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);`
- and to make item.xml image only (make button gone)

but no use.

Does anyone have some other explanation?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot about the problem? Also, include your `onCreateViewHolder(...)` and `onBindViewHolder(...)` in your question.

Comment: It looks the same as in first two questions above. onCreateViewHolder just inflates item.xml and returns CustomViewHolder created with such view. Apart from click listener, in onBindViewHolder I use Glide.with(context).load(posterUrl).placeholder(placeholder).into(customViewHolder.imvPoster);. See my answer.

Comment: What version of the support lib do you use?

Comment: @Gergely Kőrössy - v7

Comment: I meant like 23.2.0 etc.

Comment: I am using 25.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the answers for other questions mentioned above, changing from match_parent to wrap_content should solve the problem. But it does not, and if anyone can explain why I will accept that as the answer.

I have solved it with reversing back to match_parent for RecyclerView and relating layout heights, and setting `setAutoMeasureEnabled(false)` for `GridLayoutManager` (third line in the above `getGridLayoutManager()` function - just changed `true` to `false`).